# Extract certain info from a cell? via Google AppScript

Tags: google-apps-script

I need to extract data and it is new/different everyday because we get different senders every day

EX Data)

Zelle payment from BOBAME LLC WFCT0RKCP8I0

Zelle payment from BOBAME LLC WFCT0RKCP8OO

Zelle payment from BOBA FOR YOU LLC WFCT0RKCP5M4

Zelle payment from SON TRAN BACkvl78wpv0

Zelle payment from BOBA LLC WFCT0RKCP9V0

Zelle payment from SUNSCREEN LLC 18423268496

Zelle payment from JOSEFINA TRAN WALKER BACq0FWEi1gt

Zelle payment from SEAMEN SIAM WFCT0LOPB6YK

Zelle payment from JEFFREY PINAY BACrz84wt531

Zelle payment from PURE TEA NIC CORPORATION 18423485647

Zelle payment from C B D TEA STATION LLC BACnj5tyf0fu

Zelle payment from BOBA FOR YOU LLC WFCTERCP94J

Zelle payment from SEA TOTION, INC BACbmwsw1q4z

Zelle payment from VEW MEXING LLC WFCT0WSX5TPL

Zelle payment from TAMLE LIPPIN LLC 1842573132P

Zelle payment from BOBA LLC WFCT0RKCP299

Zelle payment from BUBBLY TEA LLC 18428472475

Zelle payment from GOODS2YOU LLC 18427266067

To

BOBAME LLC

BOBAME LLC

BOBA FOR YOU LLC

SON TRAN

BOBA LLC

SUNSCREEN LLC

JOSEFINA TRAN WALKER

SEAMEN SIAM

and so on

this is my code from app script

```
function extractBusinessName(input) {
  var words = input.split(' ');
  var fromIndex = words.indexOf('FROM');
  var businessName = words.slice(fromIndex + 1, -1);
  return businessName.join(' ');
}
```

I used it yesterday and it gave me what I want but today it gives me this

Zelle payment from BOBAME LLC

I need it to give me

BOBAME LLC

Comment: Although, unfortunately, I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question and I don't know your actual values, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If my answer was not useful for your actual situation, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected result, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

In this case, it supposes that your sample values are put into column "A".

```js
function extractBusinessName(input) {
  return input.map(r => r.map(c => (c.toString() && c.includes("from")) ? c.match(/from(.*) /)[1].trim() : null));
}
```

- In this case, please put `=extractBusinessName(A1:A)` into a cell.
- If you use a built-in formula, how about the following function?

  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A,"from(.*) ")))
  ```

#### Testing:

When this script is used, the following result is obtained.

[image]

#### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)
- [REGEXEXTRACT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244?sjid=16600072563639096586-AP)

Comment: @tankaike I did not try your code yet but I found out my problem! my code before had ("FROM") and because once the payment process through it will change to "from". the code didnt register it so it would bug out

Comment: @Testing Testing Thank you for replyig. About `@tankaike I did not try your code yet`, I deeply apologize for my poor skill. About `but I found out my problem! my code before had ("FROM") and because once the payment process through it will change to "from". the code didnt register it so it would bug out`, unfortunately, I cannot understand your current situation. Can I ask ou about the detail of it?

Comment: Please do not apologize, I should have explain properly and replied faster!

Comment: @Testing Testing Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, from `Please do not apologize, I should have explain properly and replied faster!`, I couldn't understand your current situation. Can I ask ou about the detail of it?